# Space vector and bias voltage

Tags: voltage, three-phase, ac-motor

I am trying to learn the space vector modulation but I am wondering how is the bias voltage in a 3-phase system regarded by the space vector?

Comment: Can you link to an article that gives some context?

Comment: Is this for brushless DC motors, or something from SpaceX?

Comment: @Aaron yes, exactly